# Firebase Realtime Database Filter Data in Nested List

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wanted to retrieve filtered data from db according to `extra_Cat` value like *31*

I am able to retrieve full data easily but unable to put filter in it

Note: I have checked almost every solution, If duplicate please reply then tag duplicate

my code is

```
 DBConnection dbConnection=new DBConnection();
        postRef=dbConnection.database.getReference("Data");
        postRef.child("extra_Cat").orderByKey().equalTo("*31*").limitToLast(500).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                long as= dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                Log.d("Data", String.valueOf(as));
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
            }
        });
```

and JSON is

[image]

```
    "32161" : {
  "author_name" : "Talented+Desk",
  "cat_ID" : "%2A7%2A",
  "cat_name" : "%E0%A4%96%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%B2",
  "content" : "A4%B5A4%A8%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%AE+%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%88%E0%A4%82%7C%E2%80%9D%3C%2Fp%3E%0A",
    "extraCat" : [ "*31*", "*14*" ],
  "fea_image" : "https%3A%2F%2Fwww.talentedindia.co.in%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2018%2F03%2Faajeevan-pratibandh-Steve-Smith.jpg",
  "post_comment" : "0%A4%BF%E0%A4%AF%E0%A5%8B%E",
  "post_date" : "2018-03-26",
  "post_id" : "32161",
  "post_slug_name" : "kangaroos-protest-against-less-punishment",
  "post_status" : "publish",
  "post_time" : "10%3A45%3A40",
  "post_video" : "",
  "slider_image1" : "",
  "slider_image2" : "",
  "slider_image3" : "",
  "slider_image4" : "",
  "title" : "%E0%A4%94%B8%E0%A4%9C%E0%A4%BE+%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%B0+%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%A7"
},
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot create a query based on values that exist within an array. As I see in your database, `extraCat` is an array which contains 2 values, `*31*` and `*14*`.

In order to solve this, you need to change your database structure a little bit. So your `extraCat` node should look like this:

```
extraCat
  |
  --- "*31*": true
  |
  --- "*14*": true
```

As you can see, the `extraCat` node the is now a `Map`. The corresponding query should look like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = rootRef.child("Data")
    .orderByChild("extra_Cat/*31*")
    .equalsTo(true)
    .limitToLast(500)
    .addValueEventListener(/* ... */)
```

Comment: one extra question : it retrieves 500 entries then filter for specific category, But i wanted 500 entries of that cat is it possible to do it here or else i have to do it elsewhere

Comment: No, you filter on a particular category and then you get those 500 entries according to that category. You can only filter according to one category. Firebase does not allow you to filter based on multiple categories.

Comment: No, you got me wrong, with this code i am getting only 200 (retrieving 500 then filtering *31* (i think so ))entries because in last 500 entries 300 were from different category, this is i want 500 entries with  *31*

Comment: This is waht this code does. Il filters 500 entries with 31.

Comment: no that is what i am saying it is giving only 200 entries with cat *31*  from last 500 posts. And i want is  last 500 entries with *31*, I don't know why its not working

Comment: It is because you only have 200 records in your database of category 31. If  you are using `limitToLast(5)` is will display only 5 but if you using `limitToLast(500)` and you only have 200, only 200 will be displayed. And this in happening only if you don't have any other limitations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167619/discussion-between-amit-kumar-pawar-and-alex-mamo).

Comment: Note that for this solution to work efficiently, you will need to define an index on each child on `extra_Cat`. Since this requires that you modify the security rules for each category, it's usually not feasible. Instead I'd recommend storing extra data to allow an inverse lookup. See my answer here for details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I tried to solve OP's issue using the existing database structure. Storing extra data to allow an inverse lookup, it always a good option. Maybe I should have recommended it, in the first place. Thank you again Frank for your comment.

Answer (score 3):

First you are using wrong reference path. The current you are using is *`Data/extra_cat`*. As I see in your Firebase structure it should be *`Data/32343/extraCat`*.
You can't use `.child("extra_Cat").orderByKey().equalTo("*31*")` because the *`*31*`* is not of the *`extra_Cat`* keys value. The value is in the list.